# Start (and keep running) process from PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winapi, process

I need to start a process from PowerShell (5.0) that will keep running even if PowerShell interpreter will close.

In Python this is done by using process creation flag `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` which is part of native NT api.

How can i start process from PowerShell with this flag? (or some other way that will have same result e.g. process can run even if interpreter gets closed)

EDIT: `Start-Process "process.exe" $args` does start the process, but it will get terminated if PowerShell interpreter gets closed

EDIT no.2: What about .NET or C#? I heard they can be inlined in PS so if those have some standard way to run process in way described above i'm totally fine with inlining them

Comment: [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

Comment: i think nothing need todo here at all. child no depend from parent. and powershell not run in job at all, (but really need even more `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` ). so simply run process as is will be enough

Comment: @JamesC. `Start-Process "process.exe" $args` is what is started with but process will get killed when powershell script reaches EOF or if interpreter gets terminated externally, so if there is specific option/argument that needs to be added i would appreciate being bit more specific

Comment: I think you can do a task scheduler and run it in the background...

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what you are trying to achieve. Maybe a scheduled task or a Service would be suitable, but that depends on the actual need.

Comment: So you're looking for a background processes equivalent to `myprocess &` on linux? Do you want it to continue running after you log off?

Comment: @JamesC. in this case process.exe is a gui application that will likely finish itself (depending on configuration) and user can also close it. But i guess it should quit when user log off. (just like most of gui apps)